# Separate values for the model and view in your input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All I want to do is have the numbers I type automatically formatted to $  as I type it in the input but keep the actual model as number only without the $. I tried it different ways but all I have now is if I have some value already in the model (instead of null) it'll show with $ . But if it's null or if I delete everything inside the input and start from scratch then the values are not being formatted as $ . What am I doing wrong?
Here's a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rmzqomzz/1/

```
angular.module('HelloApp', []);

function myTest() {

 return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, iAttrs, ngModel) {
      console.log(iAttrs.myTest);
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(modelValue){
          if(!modelValue) return;
          if(iAttrs.myTest == 'money'){
              return '$ '+modelValue;
          }else{
              return modelValue +' %';
          }
      });
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
          return viewValue.replace('$', '').trim();
      });
      scope.$watch(
          function(){
              return ngModel.$modelValue;
          }, function(newValue, oldValue){
              console.log('value changed '+ newValue);        
          }, true
      );


  }
 };
};

angular.module('HelloApp').directive('myTest', myTest);

angular.module('HelloApp').controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
$scope.mon = {'balu':null};
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a filter?

```
<input ng-model="num">
    <p>Value {{num | currency:"$"}}</p>
</body>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency